# How to use COVALENT UI with nativescript angular app

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, teradata-covalent

I wanted to use covalent ui components  with a nativescript angular app. Is that possible? I am a newbie with nativescript development. Can we use any angular library with nativescript?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use covalent ui components on nativescript as those work only on web.

You can search [here](http://market.nativescript.org/) for ui components and other plugins

And you can use angular libraries as long as they don't use DOM api's, for example NGRX will work like a charm ;)